# Wordpress theme for tutorial as similar to mentioned in picture

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Since long I have been looking for the wordpress theme which should look like exactly as shown in the picture. However I have not found any, any suggestions or links would be most welcomed.

Here I need an additional functionality on the top menu bar where one should be able to choose different categories and the sidebar on left should change accordingly.

I have only figured out LMS however it is too much for my need.

[image]